# Fuzzy Wuzzy logic on a single pandas data frame to replace similar values with the most occurring instance

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy, fuzzy

I am facing a problem in applying fuzzy logic for data cleansing in python. My data looks something like this

```
data=pd.DataFrame({'Employer':['Deloitte','Accenture','Accenture Solutions Ltd','Accenture USA', 'Ernst & young',' EY', 'Tata Consultancy Services','Deloitte Uk'], "Count":['140','120','50','45','30','20','10','5']})
data
```

I am using fuzzy logic to compare the values in the data frame. The final output should have a third column with result like this:

```
data_out=pd.DataFrame({'Employer':['Deloitte','Accenture','Accenture Solutions Ltd','Accenture USA', 'Ernst & young',' EY', 'Tata Consultancy Services','Deloitte Uk'], "New_Column":["Deloitte",'Accenture','Accenture','Accenture','Ernst & young','Ernst & young','Tata Consultancy Services','Deloitte']})
data_out
```

So if you see, I want less occurring values to have a new entry as a new column with the most occurred value of its type. That is where fuzzy logic is helpful.

Comment: Hm while e.g. the matching of `Accenture <-> Accenture Solutions Ltd` should be rather simple I am not sure how to match `Ernst & young <-> EQ`, since they are not very similar at all.

Answer (score 2):

Most of your duplicate companies can be detected using fuzzy string matching quite easily, however the replacement `Ernst & young <-> EY` is not really similar at all, which is why I am going to ignore this replacement here. This solution is using my library [RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/rapidfuzz), but you could implement something similar using FuzzyWuzzy aswell (with a little more code, since it does not has the extractIndices processor).

```py
import pandas as pd
from rapidfuzz import process, utils

def add_deduped_employer_colum(data):
    values = data.values.tolist()
    employers = [employer for employer, _ in values]

    # preprocess strings beforehand (lowercase + remove punctuation),
    # so this is not done multiple times
    processed_employers = [utils.default_process(employer)
        for employer in employers]
    deduped_employers = employers.copy()

    replaced = []
    for (i, (employer, processed_employer)) in enumerate(
            zip(employers, processed_employers)):
        # skip elements that already got replaced
        if i in replaced:
            continue

        duplicates = process.extract(
            processed_employer, processed_employers[i+1:],
            processor=None, score_cutoff=90, limit=None)

        for (_, _, c) in duplicates:
            deduped_employers[i+c+1] = employer
            """
            by replacing the element with an empty string the index from
            extractIndices stays correct but it can be skipped a lot 
            faster, since the compared strings will have very different
            lengths
            """
            processed_employers[i+c+1] = ""
            replaced.append(i+c+1)

    data['New_Column'] = deduped_employers

data=pd.DataFrame({
    'Employer':['Deloitte','Accenture','Accenture Solutions Ltd','Accenture USA', 'Ernst & young',' EY', 'Tata Consultancy Services','Deloitte Uk'],
    "Count":['140','120','50','45','30','20','10','5']})

add_deduped_employer_colum(data)
print(data)
```

which results in the following dataframe:

```
                    Employer Count                 New_Column
0                   Deloitte   140                   Deloitte
1                  Accenture   120                  Accenture
2    Accenture Solutions Ltd    50                  Accenture
3              Accenture USA    45                  Accenture
4              Ernst & young    30              Ernst & young
5                         EY    20                         EY
6  Tata Consultancy Services    10  Tata Consultancy Services
7                Deloitte Uk     5                   Deloitte
```

Comment: Hello, we are trying to implement your code, but it gives us the following error:  module 'rapidfuzz.process' has no attribute 'extractIndices' on the code:   duplicates = process.extractIndices(
            processed_employer, processed_employers[i+1:],
            processor=None, score_cutoff=90, limit=None), we are new to this process, any help is really appreciated it.

Comment: I think this API only existed in very early versions. Nowadays you can just use `process.extract` which returns a list of tuples where the tuple includes the corresponding index.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, we have tried your solution, but still says:  too many values to unpack (expected 2)...

Comment: I updated the API usage. process.extract returns tuples with 3 elements, where the third element is the index.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used fuzzy but can assist as follows

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Employer':['Accenture','Accenture Solutions Ltd','Accenture USA', 'hjk USA', 'Tata Consultancy Services']})
df
```

You did not give an explanation why Tata remains with the full name. Hence I assume it is special and mask it.

```
m=df.Employer.str.contains('Tata')
```

I then use np.where to replace anything after the first name for the rest

```
df['New_Column']=np.where(m, df['Employer'], df['Employer'].str.replace(r'(\s+\D+)',''))
df
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this will not solve my problem as i have a huge data set containing different company names. Let me actually rephrase the question for better understanding

Comment: Thanks, clarity is as important as the answer itself

Comment: Looking forward for a solution from you :)

Comment: You did not give an explanation why Tata remains with the full name. Hence I assume it is special and mask it.. See edit

Comment: Hi, No wwnde, I am not looking for this solution. I am facing a bigger challenge. People are entering different version of company names as per there convenience. For example, I am prefer ti write Accenture, but you may write Accenture Ltd. So, My goal is to bring symmetry to the data base and replace Accenture Ltd with Accenture (which had max count). the same logic goes for other companies. That's y i am using a Fuzzy logic. I hope this  explanation would help. I am not looking for a REGX solution.